# Plot of partial derivative looks wrong and does not match the surface plot of the function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have a function and I'm using Wolfram Cloud to analyze it.

```
F[p_, n_] := InverseBetaRegularized[0.1, p*n + 1, (1 - p)*n + 1]
```

When I plot the function, it looks very similar to `F[p_, n_] := p` for large values of `n`.

```
Plot3D[F[p, n], {p, 0, 1}, {n, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

Now I try to find partial derivative at `p=0`:

```
dFdp[p_, n_] := D[F[p, n], p]

dFdpAtP0[n_] := ReplaceAll[dFdp[p, n], {p -> 0}]
```

From the 3D plot, these derivatives should be very close to 1.

Yet, I get very different plot:

```
Plot[dFdpAtP0[n], {n, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

There are several problems with this plot: It's not continuous, not monotonic and not close to 1.

I'm not very experienced with Wolfram or Mathematica. What's the problem with the derivative plot?

P.S.

```
dFdpAtP0[n] =
```

[image]

Comment: Can you plot myF in the same section? You have the derivative of myF at p=0 for n from one to 1000, which would be a cut in your 3D plot running from the left frontal corner to the left backwards corner - i'd expect the derivative to be 0 tbh. "along the p-axis" i would expect to mean n=0 (or some other constant up to 1000) and p=0 to 1

Comment: @Bill I've updated my question. Intermediate variables have not changed anything.

Comment: @bukwyrm I've updated and clarified my question.

Comment: Maybe there is some jumping between branches of the logarithm or of any of the special functions is involved... Might be an indication for a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Plot3D[Derivative[1, 0][F][p, n], {p, 0, 1}, {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Thereby I redused the range of n because the evaluation time...

For `p=0`

```
Plot[Derivative[1, 0][F][.0, n],  {n, 1, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

the smooth plot ends at  `n~170`

Comment: Ulrich, the discontinuities only appear in the range $n \in [80,200]$ or so. So, they cannot appear in your plot.

Comment: Henrik, thank you for your hint. I edited my answer, the derivative for `p=0` looks smooth in the range `1<n<170`. Outside the derivative seems to be undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly a problem of precision.

Allow as much extra precision as possible  `$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity`  and use 1/10 instead of 0.1 in function definition.

Even then `Plot` can't do the job up to n==1000; do it with `Table` .

But I noticed, even Table suceeds only in reasonalble time, when n are even numbers. Don't know why.

```
tab = Table[{p, n, Derivative[1, 0][F][p, n]}, {p, 0, 1, 1/20}, {n, 0,
         1000, 40}] // N[#, 8] &

tab2 = Table[{p, n, Derivative[1, 0][F][p, n]}, {p, 0, 1, 1/20}, {n, 
      0, 20, 4}] // N[#, 8] &
```

I splitted it up to get better resolution at low n. `// N[#, 8] &` forces exact evaluation, simply `//N` won't do it.

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[Join[tab, tab2], 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Derivative[1, 0][F][0, n], {n, 1, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, .4}]
```

[image]